# Behavior of folder.getMessages() during MessagingException

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have an email service that is pulling messages from the inbox, and am using a try/catch for MessagingExceptions. I'm calling folder.getMessages(int start, int end) to grab a batch of existing emails.

When a MessagingException is thrown due to folder.getMessages(), will the returned array ever be partially filled with messages, or will the result always be null?

Answer (score 1):

If the method throws an exception, it can't return a value.